# Flexbox children have not the same size

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a `display:flex` container. Inside there are two other divs that have both `flex-grow: 1`.
I expected that both fields should have *exactly* the same size.
But after opening my page, it turns out they don't. 
They have *almost* the same size, but one field gets 55%, the other 45%.
How can that be?

```css
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="first">bla</div>
  <div class="second">blub</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-basis:0 to both

Comment: That was easy! I expected the answer to be easy... but why this behaviour? For me it does not make any sense...?

Comment: the flexbox algorithm consider 3 properties, you are using 2 (grow and shrink) but missing the basis. Read more about this property and you will better understand